# Eclipse - E4: Removing a Placeholder in a non-active perspective grabs control from active perspective

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp, e4

I've tried to place may concern in an eclipse forum weeks ago, but got no response. Maybe they are on holiday or the forum has already started its process of dying in order to find a new conversation platform. Nevertheless...

Now to my little big problem while developing on e4 rcp.

I've got a little issue with those MPlaceholders. What I'm trying to archive is, to remove every placeholder (one per perspective) referencing the same MPart, when closing any placeholder.

In order to realize this I've hijacked the EPartService method 'hidePart(MPart, boolean)' to remove the placeholders and finally to remove the part from windows.sharedElements.
Everything works fine with one exception. When closing a placeholder in a non-active perspective, its parent partstack activates a different part and grabs the control from the active perspective.
You can only see this, if the activated part is also visible in the active perspective.

I've already filed a bug for this: [520238](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=520238)

But I'm absolutely unsure if this strategy leads to a total mess-up in the application model.

Is there a better alternative to get this working?

Thank you in advance 
Matthias

Comment: I just wonder why this question was downvoted.

Comment: If something is wrong with this post, please tell me.